# Why doesn't this method throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I don't understand the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
        int numbers[] = new int[5];
        int total = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            total += numbers[i];
        }   
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("First Exception");
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't Java throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since `numbers[5]` is not an existing element of the array? It has only indexes 0-4, right?

Comment: Where do you believe it's trying to access `numbers[5]`?

Comment: `i < 5` means that `i` will never reach 5 in the loop.

Comment: Consider adding a print statement so you see which values `i` assumes throughout the program run. Or make use of the debugger to step through - that's a valuable tool.

Comment: Thx Arnaud, didn't know that :-) - Problem solved

Comment: @Arnaud `i` _will_ reach 5, right after executing the body when `i == 4`; but the condition `i < 5` is then evaluated to false, and the loop breaks without executing the body.

Comment: @AndyTurner : You're right, the explanation was a bit short :)

Comment: @AndyTurner so it is correct to say i will never reach 5 _in the loop_?

Comment: @eis it really depends what you mean by "in the loop": within the loop _body_, no; within the evaluation of the syntactic unit representing the for statement, yes.

Comment: @AndyTurner for example in the context of while loops, if the condition is false already at the beginning, we say "execution never entered the while loop". I would think vocabulary would work the same way for for loops.

Comment: The condition in your loop is `i < 5`. So when `i` will take up the values 0,1,2,3,4 and when i=5, the condition becomes false, hence it would come out of the loop.
Therefore, `numbers[5]` is not evaluated and hence there is no error.

If the condition was `i<=5`, then your code would throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception for calculating `numbers[5]` which is invalid.

Comment: I was looking at the "whole" condition. So it stops at 5 and will not execute the loop right?. I expected it to do it one last time as i ++ happens one last time at 4 :-)

Comment: @Karl `i++` happens one las time but the condition `i < 5` is evaluated after that

Comment: You can debug you code with for loop using any IDE. May be better understanding of for loop concept.

Answer (score 2):

In for loop the increment happens after the iteration ends and only then the condition is done.

So in your case when `i` is 4 the condition will be true and the loop continues, when the iteration ends `i` will be incremented to 5 and the condition will be false so the loop will stop and the loop will never work when `i=5`

Answer (score 1):

I think it helps if we rewrite the for loop to a while loop.

The for statement of the form

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    statements;
}
```

is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to

```java
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    statements;
    i++;
}
```

As you can see, the *update part* of the for loop behaves as if it were the last statement of the loop body. So at the end of the iteration, **i = 5** (right after i++ has been executed). Then the while condition is evaluated, which results in false and the loop is immediately ended.

So, yes, one *could* say that `i` *has* reached 5 (otherwise the loop condition would never be `false`), but `i` can never be accessed while it has the value `5`.

The Java Language Specification, [§ 14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) describes exactly how the basic *for* loop works.

---

<sup>1</sup> The difference here is that if we rewrite it to a *while* statement, the `i` variable is in scope even when the loop has terminated. With a *for* statement, `i` is only in scope within the for clauses (*ForInit*, the *for* condition and *ForUpdate*) and the loop body.